# What was the first action RPG with rogue-like elements?

Tags: gaming-history, roguelikes

What was the first action RPG game to also have roguelike elements like procedurally generated dungeons, permanent death (aka permadeath), etc.?

Note: By "action RPG" I mean Diablo-style games.

Comment: Interesting question, but can you please elaborate on your requirements? Exactly what you consider requisite for the game to be considered *action* and *rpg*? For example, Rogue (1980) as far as I know was turn based (like most modern rogue like - enemies don't move until you move) so it is no "action", while games like "Dandy" (1983) had no real "RPG" mechanics (you had food and hp,but nothing like "level up" or "skills". "Dandy" inspired game "Gauntlet" at lest had 4 different characters with different skills)

Comment: Seen the edit, helps a bit but leaves still some space for interpretation. I suggest you add a list of requirements and specify if all of them must be present or just some. Based on your current wording I **assume** you want something that has random generation, real time combat (NOT turn based) and permanent death (player has only one "life") and all these three requirement must be present to qualify

Answer (score 1):

My guess will be [Advanced Dungeons & Dragons: Cloudy Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Dungeons_%26_Dragons:_Cloudy_Mountain), an Intellivision game released in 1982:

> The gameplay involves exploring a series of randomly generated scrolling mazes, looking for treasures and weapons with which to defeat monsters, and recovering the two pieces of the Crown of Kings.

[image]